# Can I select all same fields of a json field regardless of their path

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a lot of json files stored in a json data type column in postgres. Now there are plenty of places where the key "warning" can apply. Unfortunately I can not get a json schema so I can not know in advance where exactly all the warning keys can show up. So I would like to do something like this:

```
select report #> '{*,warning}' from foo;
```

Is there some way to us wildcards in paths? Or is the only way to dynamically traverse a json value lets say key by key recursively in pl/sql function? (if even possible to return a set of cursors as one big cursor).

EDIT:
Interestingly the good old xml data type can do exactly what I need. So I am a bit puzzled why we can not do the same operations on json documents like:

```
select xmlexists('//town[text() = ''Toronto'']' PASSING BY REF '<root><oldtowns><town>Toronto</town><town>Ottawa</town></oldtowns><newtowns><town>Toronto</town><town>Ottawa</town></newtowns></root>');

select * from xmltable('//town' PASSING by ref '<root><oldtowns><town>Toronto</town><town>Ottawa</town></oldtowns><newtowns><town>Toronto</town><town>Ottawa</town></newtowns></root>' columns town varchar path 'text()')
```

Comment: Normalise your table, do not keep stuffing everything inside jsons. Remember, it's a relational database you're still working on.

Comment: I can not normalize it as I can not derive the dedicated schema (as mentioned). This time I am in a lucky position since I have the same document in xml. And yes guess what good old xml can handle all use cases needed.

Comment: You should be able to do this with postgres 12 and the new json_path functions, but until that is released, it sounds like you are better off with the xml.